# describe a bedroom "filled" with furniture

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word that will give the illustration of a room "crowded" or "filled" with furniture. I know those words are not correct, so could someone give a more eloquent way of describing the room?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.  *Crowded* implies a large number of people, but this question is specifically asking about furniture.

Comment: My bedroom at grandma's house was *crammed* with old furniture; everything from broken rocking chairs, 30's stands nightstands, to an old player piano with a busted foot-treadle.

Comment: Why would *filled* or *crowded* be incorrect?  Sure, *crowded* does suggest people are involved, but at most this hints at personification of the furniture, not an "incorrect" sentence, surely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Cluttered** comes to mind when describing a room that has so many contents that it impairs movement through it.  It is most often applied to extra "stuff" over and above the furniture, but a room with too much furniture is also cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

The room was "overcrowded" and "crammed" with furniture.

Answer (score 0):

The word that springs to mind is 'furnished' or perhaps 'over-furnished' if there is too much...